# How to get print the value of a variable which is extracted by regural expression extractor in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to track the value by printing it to the log but getting void as an answer.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3syXB.png)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to see the variable names along with values is using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)

[image: Debug Sampler]

However if you need to print all the extracted values to JMeter log for some reason you need to slightly change your script to look like:

```
log.info("Detected " + vars.get("urls_matchNr") + " URLs");

for (int i=1; i<= Integer.parseInt(vars.get("urls_matchNr")); i++) {

    log.info("URL # " + i + ": " + vars.get("urls_" + i));

}
```

`vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance so this way you get read/write access to all Jmeter Variables in scope.

[image: Beanshell Log Variables]

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article for more information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter

Comment: This answers is very helpful and understanding ...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems in your script.

1) You are extracting Match No: -1, which is not right (Check your regular expression extractor). You can either chose 0 for random match or any positive number for the respective match.

2) In BeanShell assertion, you are trying to retrieve the value as 
logs.info("the" +urls);- which is not the right way to do.
To get the value of a variable in BeanShell we have to use "vars.get" method.

So change your assertion to logs.info("the" +vars.get("urls")); and try once.

Comment: If the match number is set to a negative number, then all the possible matches in the sampler data are processed.

Comment: I updated beanshell script as 

    var urls=vars.get("urls");
    log.info(""+urls)
and also update random number to positive number, Now I am  getting my desired result                                                                                                         Thank you Gayathri